# Extracting field values (of certain entity type and bundle) from form/form_state

Tags: 7, entities

I have fields of entity type `foo` and bundle name `bar`. These fields get rendered as an HTML `input` inside a form. There are other fields present on the form, but I'm only interested in foo/bar ones.

The number of foo/bar fields is dynamic (as are the names). I need a way to extract their name/value pairs.

Here's my situation in code:

```
function submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Get all the submitted data that is backed by a field of
  // an entity type 'foo' and bundle 'bar'
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see `hook_form_submit()` anywhere. Do you mean [`hook_node_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7) or [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)?

Comment: Sorry beth, that was a bad choice for a name (it's changed now). I actually use `hook_form_alter` where I do `$form['#submit'][] = 'submit';`. The point is: I can see the values I need inside `$form` and `$form_state` but am looking for a proper way to get them out.

Comment: What do you mean by 'see' and 'get them out'?

Comment: Well, using a debugger I can see that both objects ($form and $form_state) contain the field values I'm looking for. Now I wonder if there's perhaps a function in D7 that I could use to extract these values (that correspond to certain entity_type/bundle).

Comment: Does something like `$my_var = $form['foo']['bar']` not work? I feel like I'm not understanding something here.

Comment: Oh, and are you familiar with [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and [`dpm()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7)?

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work. I've rephrased my question a bit, hopefully it makes more sense now.

As for Devel, yep, I'm familiar with it (am constantly abusing dd() :).

Comment: To which form are you adding your submission handler? Is it a form to edit the entity? Does it contain fields from other entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved my problem with [`field_info_instances`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7) function.

`array_keys(field_info_instances('foo', 'bar'))` gives me the names of the fields I'm interested in.

At this point, all I have to do is to loop thru the field names and access their values like this:

`$form_state['values'][$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']`

Works like a charm. But do let me know if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

All the field values are in `$form_state['values']`. See: [`drupal_form_submit`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7).

You might also be interested in using [`hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7) instead of `hook_form_alter` to target a particular content type. Your function would look like: `'mymodule_form_' . $form_id . '_alter'`.

Or at least an:

```
if ($form_id == 'your_content_type') { // add new submit handler }
```

in `hook_form_alter`.

Also use `LANGUAGE_NONE`, without quotes, instead of 'und' ie `$some->var[LANGUAGE_NONE]['value'];`

---

Also for future reference: 
Install the Devel module, use [`dpm($form_state,'$form_state');`](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/dpm/7)

When you use `dpm` you get nice dumps of variables that look like:
http://goo.gl/qIf6p

Comment: My solution (using `field_info_instances`) works fine with hook_form_alter but I'll keep your suggestion in mind. Plus, thank you for devel recommendation, I'm already a happy user. :)